# jQuery/CoffeeScript: hide div if all radios are false, but show if any is true

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a `div` that I need shown if a user answers yes (clicks "True" radio) to any of 4 questions. But if they answer false to all, then hide the `div`. What I've been having trouble with is if a user changes his/her mind and goes back and chooses the other option on any question. I've written this CoffeeScript method to handle it:

```
$ ->
  numberFalse = 0
  numberTrue = 0
  hideIfAllNo = ->
    $('.legal-information').find('input[type=radio]').each ->
      if $(this).is(':checked') and $(this).val() is 'false'
        if numberFalse >= 4 then return else numberFalse += 1
        if numberTrue >= 1 then numberTrue -= 1 else numberTrue = 0
      else if $(this).is(':checked') and $(this).val() is 'true'
        if numberTrue >= 4 then return else numberTrue += 1
        if numberFalse >= 1 then numberFalse -= 1 else numberFalse = 0
    if numberFalse is 4
      $('.legal-info-extra-info').slideUp('fast')
    if numberTrue >= 1
      $('.legal-info-extra-info').slideDown('fast')

  $('.legal-information input[type=radio]').on 'change', ->
    hideIfAllNo()
```

The issue here (other than some potentially questionable style choices; feel free to weigh in on those, too) is that a user can increment `numberFalse` or `numberTrue` by clicking back and forth on the same 2 radio buttons for a single question. At that point, or if they go back and make different selections on multiple questions, the counts get messed up. I had considered appending elements to an array and counting the array length, but that quickly got messy. How should I handle a user changing his/her mind?

### Edit

I've tried to store the true and false values in attributes on an object, but calling `$('.legal-information').find('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('value','true');` just sets `value` to `true`. Is there a way to just get an array of the `true` attrs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does these local variables holding amount of true and false radios used elsewhere? If no, you can skip this sum and just show this div on any `true` checked like this:

```
$ ->
  $('.legal-information input[type=radio]').on 'change', ->
    if $('.legal-information input[type=radio][value=true]:checked').length  > 0
      $('.legal-info-extra-info:hidden').slideDown('fast')
    else
      $('.legal-info-extra-info:visible').slideUp('fast')
```

Comment: Yep! It was the `[value=true]` I was missing. Didn't know you could do that. Thanks!